# Java Database Connection Down Glassfish

Tags: java, oracle, glassfish, sqlexception

I have a requirement where I need to check if the database connection is down, I then send an e-mail. Below is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
         Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "username", "password");
         Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
         ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Table");
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        if(e.getMessage().contains(new String("ORA-12543"))) {
           // send email
        }
    }
}
```

I used this website to determine when the Oracle database is down: http://www.dbmotive.com/ora-12543-tnsdestination-host-unreachable/

Now, I would like to setup the JDBC Resource and JDBC Connection pool in Glassfish and use the connection from there. I have never used Glassfish. I can't seem to find what I am looking for. Once, I have setup the resources and connection pool in Glassfish I would like to know if the database is down according to the above code will this code still work or there would be any changes. I would like to know when the database is down, then send an e-mail.

Please note the above code is sample, but in my main code this code exists.

Comment: It's better: ``if(e.getErrorCode()==12543)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, you will need to use the following codes once you are using connection retrieved through JNDI datasource. (found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/pagehelp/JDBCjdbcdatasourcesjdbcdatasourceconfigconnectionpooltitle.html):)
I have also provided details on how to retrieve the JNDI datasource below.

■3113: "end-of-file on communication channel"

■3114: "not connected to ORACLE"

■1033: "ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress"

■1034: "ORACLE not available"

■1089: "immediate shutdown in progress - no operations are permitted"

■1090: "shutdown in progress - connection is not permitted"

■17002: "I/O exception"

===========================
Code to retrieve the connection from datasource

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
     com.sun.appserv.DataSource ds = (com.sun.appserv.DataSOurce) ic.lookup("jdbc/PointBase"); 
     Connection con = ds.getConnection();
     Connection drivercon = ds.getConnection(con);
```

Glassfish datasource javadoc  is [here](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/v3/api/com/sun/appserv/jdbc/DataSource.html)

If you dont want to deploy the application, but use the datasource of a remote glassfish server, get the `initialcontext` as below

```
Properties props=new Properties();    
            props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");    
            props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"iiop://URL_OF_APP_SERVER:PORT");    
            Context ctx=new InitialContext(props);    
            DataSource datasource = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jndi/mydatasource");
```

Comment: Well, the above link was found through: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756113/how-to-test-connection-to-oracle-database-using-java

Comment: Having looked at your link, it does state these error codes but are these when using Glassfish JDBC resources and JDBC connection pools or these are these error code will work under a normal standalone application?

Comment: for datasource, you need an app server. Even if your application is standalone, it needs to refer to the JNDI provided by some app server. In your case the server is glassfish. Which is a J2EE compliant server. So the error codes should be the same

Comment: So if I don't deploy to Glassfish and run the application as it is as the above code in the static main method are these error codes you provided will still work to determine that the database is down?

Comment: I have edited my answer and put more information on this. Please check.

Comment: What about if I don't deploy the application at all and I just want a standlone application as above, are the error codes the same to determine the Oracle database is down?

Comment: I have put details about that too in the end of the post. Please check.

Comment: If I don't use JNDI to connect and I connect through DriverManager.getConnection("url", "username", "password") do I still use the above error codes to determine Oracle database is down. What you have put towards the end of the post is for JNDI.

Comment: You have stated in your question "Now, I would like to setup the JDBC Resource and JDBC Connection pool in Glassfish and use the connection from there", right? So if you are setting datasource up in server, then you need to use JNDI datasource

Comment: Correct, but if I decide not use Glassfish and run in standalone will these be the error codes to determine Oracle database is down?

Comment: If you use any JNDI datasource, you can use the above codes. If you use standalone pooled datasources (e.g c3po), then you will need to check their javadoc and see what error codes they send. I didn't find any standard set of Error codes for individual datasource implementations... :(

Answer (score 0):

With the information in the question, you would like to create a jdbc resource i.e. Datasource in the Glassfish instance.You can also create a connection pool for it. Please follow this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2432/gkyan.html) to learn on how to do it. You have to change your code a bit like looking up using JNDI

```
   DataSource ds = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("jdbc/YOUR_DATASOURCE_NAME");
   Connection con = ds.getConnection();
```

instead of getting the connection using the DriverManager with the database configuration and credentials since all these information will be configured in the Glassfish server as a Datasource. JNDI based datasource is used to decouple the work of developers and deployers. There is no need for the developer to know about the configurations of the database server. Simply knowing the Datasource name will fulfill the needs of the development.Adding to that, it is simple enough to manage multiple applications to connect to the same database using a single datasource without having the datasource configurations in each application deployed individually. I'd suggest you to look on the [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28278/toc.htm) (check the correct version) on error codes to be specific on handling cases.